# Notation for Inequalities

Tags: inequality, notation

Consider the inequality $y>x$. Suppose I also know that $x=0$, so $y>0$. What would be the best way to write this? I've thought about
$$ y>x=0 $$

But that seems quite messy and I'm not sure if there's a better way to write this.

Cheers

Comment: This is what I do too. What else did you have in mind?

Comment: This seems ok. You can write $x=0, y>x \Rightarrow y>0$, if you realy want.

Comment: @DerekLuna Well, I'm not sure if perhaps there's a better notation, if instead of $x$ we'd have $f(x)$ then it might become a bit messy

Comment: @eminem That seems fair, it's pretty much the same as "
$x=0$, so $\ldots$"

Comment: In my opinion, this notation is already clean; but if you want, you can write "$y$ is strictly positive, when $x$ is $0$."

Comment: @BookOfFlames The $y>0$ was just an example. I could for example give you $y>x^2+3x-7$, and $x=3$ (so $y>11$)

Comment: @talbi In that case, I still don't see much mess there. Because $x^2+3x-7$ is constant, it's just $y>11$. Writing $>$ is another way of writing "is greater than", but more concise, and better (due to all the algebra that will go along with that).